# explicit type conversion in visual studio

Tags: cmake

I have created a c++ project, using cmake as a build system. It compiles successfully on windows (visual studio) and Linux (GCC).
On Linux platform, GCC does an explicit type conversion without any error, e.g.
from `size_t` to `unsigned short` but on windows it throws error.

How can I do the explicit type conversion using a cmake option on windows too?

Comment: "on windows it throws error" - It is better to include **exact error message** to the question post.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete code example demonstrating the issue, with the full error message. Otherwise, it is hard to understand what is going on.